# How can I unset value from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to remove one value in array and I'm using Unset function, but when I'm passing array in Unset function I got error.

array:

```
Array ( [mid] => 8 [optionsRadios2] => 0 [optionsRadios3] => 1 [optionsRadios5] => 0 [optionsRadios6] => 0 [optionsRadios7] => 1 [optionsRadios24] => 0 [optionsRadios25] => 1 )
```

I want to remove mid and I'm using like this:

```
$module=$data['mid'];
$newdata=unset($data['mid']);
```

error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'unset' (T_UNSET) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Traning\application\controllers\home.php on line 77
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use only:

```
unset($data['mid']);
```

without assign to variable.

In docs [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) return void.

Answer (score 1):

at the first look you code looks ok?

can you check this example http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b538f88a23433b767005f5a16ca99faa5eb4f8b0

```
$koko = [
 'mid' => 1, 
 'name' => 'koko'
];

print_r($koko);

echo '---------------------------';

$toto = $koko['name'];

unset($koko['name']);

print_r($koko);
echo 'and your name is : '.$toto;
```